# ASP.net core server side redirect issue on Azure

Tags: reactjs, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, react-router-v4

I have a react.js application built utilizing react-router, calling ASP.NET core 2.0 restful services for data.  I would like any server-side 404 error to just route to "/".  I have `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/")` in my startup.

When putting an explicit path in my localhost (iis express), it redirects to root when an illegal path is entered (as expected), and actually displays the appropriate page if a legal path is entered.

However when this same app is deployed on Azure, putting an illegal path or a legal path outside of root gives me this page:

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, 
or is temporarily unavailable.
```

I'm not sure if there needs to be additional Azure configuration to make this work like localhost.  Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it hosted on Azure VM or a AppService?

Comment: Hi Umar, it's deployed as an appservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just deployed this and I had no problems so I assume you have your middleware in the wrong order and it should be like this. Verify that is in this order

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/");
        app.UseDefaultFiles(); //also add this

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

> ```
>  app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/");
> ```

This should be first before any piece of middleware.  Just a side note, this piece of middleware does not cause a browser to redirect, it just rewrites the path. So in your browser, it looks like you can visit /sfsdf/sdfsdfsdgfs. This might be a problem for you because you are using React. /sfsdf/sdfsdfsdgfs will be picked up by the react-router and will lead nowhere if you dont have something to handle that. If you want to cause a redirect, replace app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/") and use

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/");
```

Again, this should be the first piece of middleware that you add and would play more nicely with your react-router.

Add this piece of middleware after your redirect middleware.

```
 app.UseDefaultFiles();
```

All this middleware does is that it looks for index.html (it does not have to be index.html, it also tries matching other files) in your site/wwwroot folder and serves that whenever a request for / comes in. So have an index.html page in the site/wwwroot which holds you react app. You probably already have this.

You don't need any virtual directories to point to /api and one for the the react app. So you can remove them both

The react application will live in an index.html file in your site/wwwroot
Your apis will live in mvc controllers. I know you have it already set up like this.

The reason why you don't need any virtual directories is ASP.Net core will handle all that for you. When you make a request to / 
It will be picked up by

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
```

This will internally rewrite the path to be /index.html

This will be then be picked up by static middleware and will return the index.html page which holds your react app and end the request.

Now say you make a request to /blah/blah. This will skip the first two pieces of middleware and hit MVC. MVC will look for a path /blah/blah. If it exists it will return something. If it does not it will be picked up by the redirect middleware that you have at the top. This will cause a redirect to / and the whole process will start again. You do not need any virtual directories to achieve this so you can remove them.

Comment: Hi Umar, no I have the same issue even when that is moved to the beginning (I switched to the redirects for now).  Get the same error.  I'm wondering if it could be my appsettings configuration.  In azure under application settings I have the following for virtual applications and directories:  1) /api = site\wwwroot 2) / = site\wwwroot\wwwroot

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope this helps

Comment: I have two because one is used for the webapi (/api) and the other is for the react app (/).  Not sure if I can get away with just one.

Comment: Ah, I see I edited my answer and I hope this makes sense

Comment: Got it Umar.  Side question but related. Say I want to stick with using  app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/").  It seems to only work one subpath deep, e.g. /sdfsdffsd.  It fails if there is two or more levels, e.g. /sdsfd/sdfsfd.  Is there a way to get this working with any level?

Comment: Do you mean you get 404 not found with two sublevels??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166540/discussion-between-umar-karimabadi-and-los-morales).